# Unable to load web page with seleniumwire

Tags: selenium, proxy, openssl, pyopenssl, seleniumwire

Unable to load the web page using seleniumwire, I am observing this error in the browser.

```
This page isn't working
xxx.xyz didn't send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

When I replace seleniumwire with selenium while initializing the webdriver, the issue is no longer observed.
Seleniumwire was working fine and the below-mentioned error started occurring a couple of days ago.

Seleniumwire version: 4.4.0
Python 3.9
MacOS Big Sur

**AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_get0_param'**

```
ERROR:seleniumwire.server:127.0.0.1:61095: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/server.py",
```

line 113, in handle root_layer() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/modes/http_proxy.py",
line 9, in **call** layer() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/tls.py",
line 285, in **call** layer() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http1.py",
line 100, in **call** layer() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py",
line 206, in **call** if not self._process_flow(flow): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py",
line 285, in _process_flow return self.handle_regular_connect(f) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py",
line 224, in handle_regular_connect layer() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/tls.py",
line 278, in **call** self._establish_tls_with_client_and_server() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/tls.py",
line 358, in _establish_tls_with_client_and_server self._establish_tls_with_server() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/tls.py",
line 445, in _establish_tls_with_server self.server_conn.establish_tls( File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/connections.py",
line 295, in establish_tls self.convert_to_tls(cert=client_cert, sni=sni, **kwargs) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/net/tcp.py",
line 382, in convert_to_tls context = tls.create_client_context( File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/net/tls.py",
line 285, in create_client_context param = SSL._lib.SSL_CTX_get0_param(context._context)
**AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_get0_param'**

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using an outdated version of the [cryptography library](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/).